# newbie php issue include function

Tags: php

I have a very basic question I just can't seem to figure out or find the answer too.  My php won't work on my local host (wamp) or when i upload it to my website/server.

I simply want to "include" two files on my index.php file to display additional html. For whatever reason, the php won't work and won't display anything outside of what is currently in my index.php file.

Here is my index.php

```html
<php? include 'inc/header.php';?>

 <div class="container">
  <p>main content.what is going on</p>
 </div>
<php? include 'inc/footer.php';?>
```

here is an example of my header.php file..

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>stuff</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Is stuff here?</h1>
 </header>
```

I just can't seem to figure it out and any thoughts would be VERY helpful.

Comment: your tags are incorrect: `<php?` should be `<?php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have PHP start tag wrong. It should be

```
<?php
```

Comment: oh gosh! I don't now how the heck I missed that. That you for your help!!